# Хранение и обновление кода

Tags: контроль-версий

Что посоветуете для хранения и обновления кода?
Нужно для личных целей что-то типа Source Safe. Хранить файлы на другом диске, забирать файл, выкладывать, хранить предыдущие версии файлов, видеть изменения. В-общем, всё что делается при совместной разработке.
... и желательно бесплатное.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Думаю, [subversion](http://www.collab.net/downloads/subversion/) + [tortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/downloads.html) тоже будет не плохо.

Comment: Установил TortoiseSVN. По-началу было непривычно, пришлось попривыкать, но уже нравится, и это именно то, что надо! Всем спасибо.

Answer (score 5):

Рекомендую [Mercurial](http://www.mercurial-scm.org/) + [TortoiseHg](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.org/). Использую на Ubuntu, но должно хорошо работать и на Windows.

Answer (score 5):

Рекомендую [Git](http://git-scm.com/). Оптимально для локального репозитория, разработки самостоятельно. Хотя для многочисленной команды наоборот - замучаетесь с мержами. Но SVN в вашем случае, мягко говоря, ни к чему.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант DropBox там хранилище бесплатное до 3х гигабайт можно расширить, есть сохранение предыдущих версий.
Если конторка маленькая то лучше именно этот вариант, в другом случае повторю пользователя a_s tortoisesvn и subversion.